# looping over a row of input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have table and the inpout fields in it are dynamic

what i am trying to is: to run a loop over each input field having a class and each select select have a different class to match if its value is 'T', do a change

i am not sure what i am doing wrong here or eventualy i am still in middle of my thoughts to how to do it,

Here is what my html looks like like

```
<select name="r1_Taskname" id="r1_Taskname" class="actualTaskName">
    <option></option>
    <option data-category="T" value="1">management</option>
<option data-category="T" value="2">Admin</option>
</select>

<input name="r1_Monday" id="r1_Monday" value="0.00" size="3" autocomplete="off" class="taskItemsDetails">

<select name="r2_Taskname" id="r2_Taskname" class="actualTaskName">
    <option></option>
    <option data-category="T" value="1">management</option>
<option data-category="T" value="2">Admin</option>
</select>

<input name="r2_Monday" id="r2_Monday" value="0.00" size="3" autocomplete="off" class="taskItemsDetails">
```

now what i am trying to do is: if the value of the input field is already filled in and greater than 0, and its corrosponding select has the data-category of T,

i want to put an change the class of the of the input field parent at the bottom to `specialCheckbox3`

which is like this

```
<div class="specialCheckbox2"><input class="checktip" type="checkbox" value="1" name="w1_Monday" id="w1_Monday"><label for="w1_Monday"></label></div>
```

here is what i am  have tried till now

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('.taskItemsDetails').each(function(i, obj) {
            // get the class of the select and check its data attribute, if its T then do action else ignore it 
        });
    }
```

Comment: the question is unclear as well as no coding effort to resolve the issue is shown.

Comment: i did started but i amconfused on the first portion of it , here is my try ```jQuery(function($){
  $('.taskItemsDetails').each(function(i, obj) {
   // get the class of the select and check its data attribute, if its T then do action else ignore it 
  });
 }```

Comment: What happens if one input along with select box have the desired data but the other one doesn't have?

Comment: the same will be not able to add data because its already added